# Is there any faster way to grep billions of mismatch patterns in more than one file?

Tags: bash, count, grep

I wrote a script that calculates all possible mismatch patterns (depending a case) like the two below (please look at grep command) and writes an output file as sh with billion lines like this one:

```
LC_ALL=C grep -ch "AAAAAAAC[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]CGA[A-Z][A-Z]G\|C[A-Z][A-Z]TCG[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]GTTTTTTT" regions_A regions_B
```

The next step is to execute all this billions grep lines and write an output.
In order to run it as fast as I can, I look only for ASCII code (all my characters are ASCII) using LC_ALL. Moreover, I split the huge grep file in 16 parts and run them separately using 16 threads.

Does anybody know any faster method to grep my patterns?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How are you executing the 16 threads?

Comment: Use something like perl and do the regex checks in a single program instead of forking billions of greps.

Comment: Is this a bioinformatics question? What is the use case?

Comment: l'L'l  --> I write 16 different sh and execute them in parallel using & and wait

Comment: 123 -> what about ram consumption using that approach?I have to pass the billion patterns in an array

Comment: Kusalananda (nice name) --> yes it is related to bioinformatics, put can be used for general purposes as well

Comment: I was just wondering if there's not already a bioinformatics package that solves the same problem... (I don't know). (ps. Prefix usernames with `@` to let them know you're replying)

Comment: It seems like you skipped a few steps to get to where you are in the question. I suggest you focus on the problem you're actually trying to solve (_how can I find specific lines in a file_), rather than attempting to speed up your proposed method. Perhaps you could [edit] your question to explain more about your starting point and the desired output.

Comment: Dear Tom, I think the question is quite understandable. I explained that I used grep LC_ALL to count (please see parameters).  I am not trying to find specific lines in a file. If someone knows a faster way to count for billions of this type of patterns from two or + files I am pretty happy to hear any suggestion.

Comment: You can change `[A-Z]` with `.`, if your domain already restricts the charset.  This should help to speed up some.  Also different regex algorithms might behave differently for different patterns.  Perhaps try the same with `awk '/pattern/{count++} END{print count}' file1 file2`

Comment: Dear karakfa, unfortunately i tried to replace A-Z with . with no difference. I also test this awk suggestion but it is slower than grep

Comment: I disagree - `grep -c` _does_ find lines in file, it just counts them instead of printing them. Either way I think it's possible that you need to rethink your approach entirely, and in order for us to help you with that you need to provide us with more information. You can trivially combine multiple regular expressions using regex OR `|` e.g. `patternA|patternB` but even that isn't going to scale very well to billions of patterns.

Comment: Dear Tom, this is exactly what I said in my previous response,....I COUNT, i am not trying to find specific lines as you proposed me to change my question in your first response. If i could reduce even for one second the count per grep would be great in this billion times search. Actually, every grep is less than a second...let s say reduce total time by 0.01